# Angular 5 How to do Show/Hide form field mat-select on change

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I want to show or hide form field when mat-select is changed. The following code I used to do a show or hide the process. But it shows an error:

> Cannot read property 'valueFieldType' of undefined.

1).html file

```
    <mat-form-field style="width: 30%">
                 <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" [value]="evaluationRuleField" id="evaluationRuleField" name="evaluationRuleField"> 
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let evaluationRuleField of evaluationRuleFields" [value]="evaluationRuleField">{{ evaluationRuleField.viewValue }}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>             
              </mat-form-field>
<!--Start Dynamically Change Field-->
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf = "evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType == 'text'">
                  <input matInput formControlName="evaluationRuleValue" placeholder="Value" [ngModel]="evaluationRuleValue" id="evaluationRuleValue" name="evaluationRuleValue" required>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf = "evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType == 'dropdwon'">
                <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" [(value)]="ruleValueFields" id="evaluationRuleField" name="evaluationRuleField" (change)="getValue()"> 
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let ruleValueField of ruleValueFields" [value]="ruleValueField.value">{{ ruleValueField.viewValue }}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>   
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf = "evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType == 'multiselect'">
                <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" formControlName="evaluationRuleField" multiple>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
              <!--Start Dynamically Change Field-->
```

2).ts file

```
    private fieldArray: Array<any> = [{evaluationRuleField:"",condition:"condition",value:"value"}];

 evaluationRuleFields = [
    {value:"field_1",valueFieldType:'text',viewValue:"Field 1"},
    {value:"field_2",valueFieldType:'dropdown',viewValue:"Field 2"},
    {value:"field_3",valueFieldType:'text',viewValue:"Field 3"},
    {value:"field_4",valueFieldType:'multiselect',viewValue:"Field 4"},
    {value:"field_5",valueFieldType:'dropdown',viewValue:"Field 5"}
  ]    {value:"field_3",valueFieldType:'text',viewValue:"Field 3"},
    {value:"field_4",valueFieldType:'multiselect',viewValue:"Field 4"},
    {value:"field_5",valueFieldType:'dropdown',viewValue:"Field 5"}
  ]
```

Comment: You have a bit too many 'evaluationRuleField' variables in your code there...

Comment: produce a plucker

Comment: (change)  will give you the selected objects array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code:

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [(value)]="selected" formControlName="evaluationRuleField" id="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select value" name="evaluationRuleField">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let evaluationRuleField of evaluationRuleFields" [value]="evaluationRuleField">
        {{evaluationRuleField.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
   {{selected}} // the selected value
```

Your Conditions:

```
<div *ngIf="selected">

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf="selected.valueFieldType === 'text'">
        <input matInput formControlName="evaluationRuleValue" placeholder="Value" [ngModel]="evaluationRuleValue" id="evaluationRuleValue"
         name="evaluationRuleValue" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf="selected.valueFieldType ==='dropdown'">
        <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" [(value)]="ruleValueFields" id="evaluationRuleField"
         name="evaluationRuleField">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let ruleValueField of ruleValueFields" [value]="ruleValueField.value">{{ ruleValueField.viewValue }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%" *ngIf="selected.valueFieldType == 'multiselect'">
        <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    {{selected | json}}
</div>
```

TS:

```
public selected: any; //  which returns an array of selected value objects incase single select then returns an object
```

And the reason behind the `undefined` because when the variable is intialized then it don't have a property like `valueFeildType`

Ex StackBlitz Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dscav5?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html

Comment: Thank Prashant Pimpale.But i want to show the form field based on the object value.Like *ngIf = "evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType == 'text'"

Comment: Yes then you can use selected.valueFeildType ='text'

Comment: same error Cannot read property 'valueFieldType' of undefined

Comment: can you give you mail id please

Comment: What happened? prashantpimpale93@gmail.com

Comment: what i would suggest produce a plucker

Comment: Plucker has nothing!

Comment: i put two files .html and ts file

Comment: I have tested on in stackblitz demo so that error is gone which is showing an undefined for feild

Comment: and stackblitz ex

Comment: ya thanks brother it working fine.but i want the fields in same row.how can do it

Comment: At a time only single field there?

Comment: is there any possible without div

Comment: Yes but I m not sure try that If condition in <mat-form-field> tag

Comment: thanks brother its working fine.I am expecting some helps from you in feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngModel so as to get the value to validate. Whatever you define in value="", will be assigned to model on selection.

Replace this :

```
 <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" 
 [value]="evaluationRuleField" id="evaluationRuleField" 
 name="evaluationRuleField"> 
              <mat-option *ngFor="let evaluationRuleField of 
 evaluationRuleFields" [value]="evaluationRuleField">{{ 
 evaluationRuleField.viewValue }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

With :

```
 <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" 
 ([ngModel])="ev" 
 id="evaluationRuleField" 
 name="evaluationRuleField"> 
              <mat-option *ngFor="let evaluationRuleField of 
 evaluationRuleFields"  [value]="evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType">{{ 
 evaluationRuleField.viewValue }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

and Then use it like :

```
  *ngIf = "ev == yourvalue"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.In this line i got error valueFieldType of undefined.<mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select Field" [value]="evaluationRuleField.valueFieldType" ([ngModel])="ev" id="evaluationRuleField" name="evaluationRuleField">

Comment: Can you produce a plunkr for this... so that I can see your code. Make sure you are using inverted comma in ngif condition, *ngIf="ev=='yourvalue' "